# How to understand the set of permutation representations of a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In *Algebra* by Michael Artin, Chapter 6, page 182 (second edition, Pearson),  Proposition 6.11.2 states that there exists a bijective correspondence between operations of a group $G$ on the indices set $S=\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and permutation representations $G\to S_n$, in which a permutation representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism from the group to a symmetric group, say, $\phi:G\to S_n$.

This is really driving me insane, because all I can imagine is that there is always solely *one* representation. My reasoning is straightforward, *for each* $g\in G$, it sends $1,\cdots,n$ to $g(1),\cdots,g(n)$, and thus corresponds to a $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma(1)=g(1),\cdots,\sigma(n)=g(n)$. So I think that the map $\phi:G\to S_n$ is completely determined by $G$ and there is thus but one representation.. Anything wrong?

Comment: The map $\phi$ is completely determined... by the operation of $G$ on $S$ ! Your notation $g\left(1\right), \ldots, g\left(n\right)$ only makes sense with reference to an operation of $G$ on $S$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg for each $g\in G$ I can do just the same thing, so doesn't $G$ completely determine the map?

Comment: @Vim:  Just remove any mis-typed tag (from your post) and it will be purged automatically in due course (because of being an used "tag").  To clarify your Question, what is $n$?  Is it the order of the group, $|G|$?  I think that's what you meant to say, and it makes all the difference.

Comment: @hardmath the author didn't seem to say anything about $|G|$, I think $n$ is just the number of elements of the indices set $S$.

Comment: Okay, I was reading too much into the title, "the set of permutation representations of a group $G$".  Yes, if group $G$ acts on a finite set $S$, we mean that each group element $g\in G$ permutes the elements of $S$, and thus the group action determines a map $\phi:G \to S_n$, the pemutation group on $S$ being known as the symmetric group $S_n$ in a bit of notational clash.  However there can be many different group actions of $G$ on finite set $S$, so $G$ does not "completely determin[e]" the map.

Comment: @hardmath So perhaps I'm misunderstanding the meaning of a "group action", I thought it meant the action imposed by any $g\in G$ on the set $S$. Maybe the correct understanding should be a "law"? Say, a $*:G\times S\to S$ where the $*$ is an *action*?

Comment: @Vim why don't you just look up the definition of a group action on wikipedia?

Comment: @oxeimon sorry for that. I've been using the textbook (without much going online for help), and I think I've been misunderstanding something all the way through..

Comment: @Vim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

A pretty good general rule is to first read the wikipedia article on whatever you're confused about before asking about it here.

Comment: My point is that the same group $G$ could act on set $S $ in more than one way.  E.g. the trivial action is for every $g\in G $ to leave every  $s\in S $ fixed.  Another action might have some items in $S $ moving.

Comment: @Vim It's always good to learn from multiple sources if possible. This helps eliminate the possibility that you're misunderstanding something due to wording or typo, and it forces you to think about how the two sources are really saying the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing that's wrong is that when you say $g(1),\ldots,g(n)$ you've already implicitly specified an action of $G$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So of course once you "know" what $g(1),\ldots,g(n)$ are, then there is only one action of $G$ on $\{1,\ldots n\}$ where $g$ acts by sending $i$ to $g(i)$.

Let's do a simple example. Let $G = \{\text{id},g\}$ be the cyclic group of order 2 (so that $g^2 = \text{id}$), and let $n = 3$, and lets look at ways that $G$ can act on the set $\{1,2,3\}$.

Of course $\text{id}$ must act trivially, on $\{1,2,3\}$, so to specify an action it suffices to determine how $g$ acts on $\{1,2,3\}$. Since $g$ has order 2, it must act as a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ with $\sigma^2 = (1)$. Thus, $\sigma$ must either be the identity permutation (1), or a transposition (12),(13), or (23). These are all legitimate choices that define a group action of $G$ on $\{1,2,3\}$, so in this case there are 4 possible actions of $G$ on $\{1,2,3\}$, defined by sending 1 to the identity permutation, and $g$ to either $(1),(12),(13)$, or $(23)$.

I mean, if you just note that a permutation representation of $G$ is just a homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_n$, it should be obvious that in general there will be many such homomorphisms. In particular, $S_n$ has plenty of automorphisms (consider conjugation by elements of $S_n$), and so composing any homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_n$ by any automorphism of $S_n$ will generally give you a different homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_n$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is much to learn.